# When using Firestore in Flutter, is there any advantage to using a Future over a Steam?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When building a Firestore-backed app in Flutter I have two primary options for displaying data from the database. `StreamBuilder()` and `FutureBuilder()`. The difference being FutureBuilder creates a widget with a one-time fetch of data from the database and doesn't listen for changes. StreamBuilder creates a stream which rebuilds the widget when data is changed.

Let's say I have some wiki-like data that is often read and rarely written so real-time updates are not important but not harmful, either. Firebase is not going to be sending a lot of unnecessary updates to the app as it's rarely changed.

Is there some tangible benefit to avoiding StreamBuilder for data that doesn't need to be updated in terms of performance, cost, features, etc? I'm having trouble understanding why I shouldn't just use StreamBuilder unless I absolutely require data to be static after rendering.

Comment: " I'm having trouble understanding why I shouldn't just use StreamBuilder unless I absolutely require data to be static after rendering." - where did you get that from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StreamBuilder()` is useful because it help you in state management later on also help you with live data.
This Method is prefable because the firebase/firestore main functionality is that it is real-time and live. So, try to use StreamBuilder()

Comment: It looks like this is the only way to go if I want to use provider for user state management as well so I guess I'll just stick to streams.

Comment: you dont necessarily need to use firebase as a realtime database so I wouldn't say that is the best reason for using a stream builder...

Answer (score 1):

In terms of cost the streamBuilder and the futureBuilder has the same pricing, if you use the Firestore caching according [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing), and this [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1868#issuecomment-509413209). However if you need to build a static data, use Future Builder.

I strongly recommend to use Stream in reason of data consistence.

Answer (score 1):

Streams rebuild automatically after 30 min of inactivity. So you are charged for the full rebuild. Future's, rebuild when you tell it too. That's how I understand it, at least. That's worth knowing if you have a big list that is supposed to be static most of the time, as Streams may end up being more expensive.